# Regulare expression

Tags: regex

I need the regular expression for below string cases,

```java
String value = "�江苏银行股份有限公司南京迈皋桥支行";
String value = "�/CNYXB/02112";
```

in both the cases only the character "�" needs to be removed and the final string values should be as below after applying regular expression,

```java
String value = "江苏银行股份有限公司南京迈皋桥支行";
String value = "/CNYXB/02112";
```

thanks in advance!!!

yes i have tried below regEx,

```java
value = value.replaceAll("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```

Comment: Try `value = value.replace("\uFFFD", "");`

Comment: *...yes i have tried below regEx...* And what happened?

Comment: @JamesKPolk it removed even the chinesa characters.

Comment: `.replace( '�', '' );` doesn't work?

Comment: You need to make clear what property of the first character that distinguishes it from the rest in your mind. One property is simply it's value, `\uFFFD`. There are other properties though, such as alpabetic, etc. See all the `is*` methods in [`Character`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you're actually asking, but you can easily remove the first character from the string:

```regex
^.
```

matches the first character at the start of the string.

If you want to remove an out-of-range character then you need to define your range.  Use multiple classes wiht octal escapes, so something like:

```regex
[\o{2444}-\o{3444}\o{40}-\o{77}]
```

without know what the characters you're looking for really are it's difficult to be more specific.

Answer (score 0):

try to use `replaceFirst` instead of `replaceAll`:

```
value = value.replaceFirst("[^\\p{ASCII}]", "");
```